# get non-translated label in Zend decorator

Tags: zend-framework

How can I get non-translated label in `class Label extends \Zend_Form_Decorator_Label`  ?
When I tried to get it like "`$this->getLabel()`" it is already translated in russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to calling `$this->getLabel()`, you can disable the translator flag on the element by calling `$element->setDisableTranslator(true)` which will disable translation of that element.

Then, when you call `getLabel()` it checks to see if the translator for that element is enabled; if enabled, the label is translated and then returned, otherwise it is returned without translation like you want.